# Wagtail, adding more fields while using AppPageMixin

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

if I have a Page class like this:

```
class LocationPage(AppPageMixin, Page):
    template = 'locations/locations_list.html'
    url_config = 'location.urls'
    ...
```

It allows me to create pages dynamically off of the LocationPage by entering objects into my Admin Model. It took me forever to get this to work but I got it.

The issue that I am having now is that I can't seem to add custom fields to the LocationPage anymore. I just need a banner image, title, and subtitle. The rest of the content comes from a loop through my Admin Model. I did what one would normally do to add fields to a page model:

```
class LocationPage(AppPageMixin, Page):
    template = 'locations/locations_list.html'
    url_config = 'location.urls'

    banner_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+"
    )
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    page_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=False)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('page_title'),
        FieldPanel('page_subtitle'),
        ImageChooserPanel('banner_image'),
    ]
```

I migrated, but when I go to my current page using LocationPage, or if I create a new page, the fields do not show. this documentation (https://wagtail-app-pages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not mention anything about how to do this or if it is possible, but I'd say it's a pretty common requirement. Having to enter static content into the template defeats the purpose of using a cms. am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share the code for your `AppPageMixin` on the question. Just a thought, maybe you have used `Model` the `AppPageMixin` without it being an abstract class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: This is the only place that I am using it, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What is AppPageMixin? I cannot see that mentioned in the Wagtail menu docs or the main Wagtail docs. Also the docs you have linked go to Wagtail menus but your questions refer to ModelAdmin (I think).

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Thank you for sticking with me, my apologies for the late response. I updated the link. I am using 'Wagtail App Pages', which has an AppPageMixin that you place on the Page model that will be the listing page to the collection.

Comment: The 'Location' model is a django model that I have setup as an AdminModel, to be controlled in Wagtail admin. I'm not sure if that is relevant. My issue is specifically with the fields I add to the LocationPage model not being available when I choose that model as the template for a wagtail page. It is because of 'Wagtail App Pages'. It does the job of retrieving and making pages for the data, but I've lost all editability. I wasn't expecting to be able to use editable pages for the DetailView's, but I don't understand why the main template ListView can't be editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't get to see this earlier, but I hope I can weigh in as the author of wagtail_app_pages. You're absolutely right to expect this to work, you should be able to add fields to your heart's content. I'm afraid I've never come across this behavior before though. If you're still having this issue, would it be possible to share a minimal setup to reproduce this issue?

Also, please feel free to let me know if you ran into documentation shortcomings. I'd like to improve the documentation, if at all possible.

[EDIT] actually, just wondering about something. Why are you using:

```
panels = [
```

instead of:

```
content_panels = [
```

or:

```
settings_panels = [
```

etc? Maybe this is a mixup from some non-page models? An AppPage is still, most definitely, a Page, so it should use the normal page panels for the admin

Comment: This is a good point. I do not know why I used panels, I might have poorly copied a tutorial. I'm still working this project and I have made a TON of advancements, but I just read this and noticed that I am not using content_panels in these sections. I thought it was because the wagtail page is a placeholder and never actually loads a wagtail page. I will need to try to fix this, as I hard-coded the banner, etc for these page types. Thanks.